# Nodejs/JavaScript module loading and references

Tags: javascript, node.js

I recently started learning JavaScript and NodeJS. I'm not sure why I see varying results. I'd really appreciate if someone can explain the nuances that's causing varying output.

```
var stream = require('stream');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter; //typeof == function

console.log(new stream().Stream() instanceof EventEmitter); // error
console.log(new stream().Stream instanceof EventEmitter); // false
console.log(stream.Stream instanceof EventEmitter); // false...

console.log(new stream.Stream() instanceof EventEmitter); // true
console.log(new stream.Stream instanceof EventEmitter); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to keep it concise, lots of these things have answers, but there is a lot here.

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter; //typeof == function
```

EventEmitter is something you typically use with `new`. E.g. `new EventEmitter()`. In older javascript you might do `function Thing() { this.someprop = 2; }` and then do `var a = new Thing()` and be able to access `a.someprop`. In ecmascript 6+ you get to use `class` sugar. Anyways. You can `new` up function implementations and get the `this` of the function. This "instance" should also have the `.constructor` property set to the EventEmitter function in your case, were you to new it up. It will also have .prototype set to EventEmitter.prototype

```
console.log(new stream().Stream() instanceof EventEmitter); // error
```

This is erroring because Stream is not a property on new stream(). and Stream is `undefined`. Accessing/invoking a property of undefined or null will always cause a runtime error.

```
console.log(new stream().Stream instanceof EventEmitter); // false
```

You should be doing `new stream() instanceof events.EventEmitter`. again, Stream is undefined and shouldn't be an instance of anything. Note that it is true that `stream == stream.Stream`; the export is a shortcut for Stream.

```
console.log(stream.Stream instanceof EventEmitter); // false...
```

The constructor itself is just a function, and a function is not an EventEmitter.

```
console.log(new stream.Stream() instanceof EventEmitter); // true
```

When you `new` a function, the "instance" returned has a prototype which is the function's prototype. That prototype can in turn have a prototype which is how prototypical inheritance works in javascript. When you access a method or property, JS walk walks the prototype chain looking for it. When you do `instanceof`, it just checks the levels of the prototype chain for a match. Basically, Stream has EventEmitter in its prototype chain somewhere. It's actually just a level above - `stream.prototype.__proto__` in the repl will show you.

```
console.log(new stream.Stream instanceof EventEmitter); // true
```

`stream === stream.Stream`, and you don't have to use parenthesis when you use `new`.

Comment: Hi, Lot of things make sense and are clear now. Dint realize stream === stream.Stream  When I do an import, the resulting stream function has multiple functions inside it like - Readable, Transform etcc... On a side note, are these functions static in nature ?

Comment: depends on which `static` you're referring to (C / Java) but the answer is static within their scope. At the top level of a file the answer is yes, and the prototype can be thought of as a static function, so if you call new 10 times the prototype is the same thing for all of them. NOTE within functions variables are always re-declared if the function is re-called. Unlike C.

Comment: Yeah...stream here is a circular reference. When I define a function, for example - var test = function() {
 function rr() {
 console.log("rr");
 }
 this.msg = "test";
}, I cannot access the functions and variables inside it unless I initiate it. I know they are scoped. So, wondering how can functions (like readable, transform, etc..) inside 'stream' be accessible without initiating 'stream' object. For example - stream.Readable (which returns a function) vs test.rr (which returns undefined).

Comment: People define them on stream.prototype. So instead of doing `this.msg = 'test'`, you do `rr.prototype.msg = 'test'`. You do the prototype assignments outside of the `rr` scope. `function T() {}; T.prototype.msg = 'test'`. Then `new T().msg is 'test'`

Comment: So if you want internal methods to be exposed without instantiating the thing you can put them on the .prototype object

Comment: Got you. Thanks a lot catalyst. Trying to understand nuances of JavaScript.